# sonarqube downgrade version

Tags: database, sonarqube, downgrade

I'm using SonarQube version 5.1 and MySQL 5.6.19:
Due to regulations I have to use the Long Term Support Version 4.5.4.

The problem is, that I get the following error message from SonarQube when I try to start SonarQube 4.5.4:

**org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings.**

Is there a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, downgrade of SonarQube is not supported. Database upgrade scripts only execute in one way, from old version to new version. So in your case, you will have to start from a clean database and analyze your projects again from scratch.

Comment: Exact. That's why it's documented to backup database before upgrading.

Comment: Is there an estimation, when there will be a LTS version for SonarQube 5.1?

Comment: The current estimate so far is that there will be a 5.2.x LTS release sometime Q3 2015.